# The difference between CI of population and CI of mean

Tags: confidence-interval, descriptive-statistics

[Drummond's paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1113/jphysiol.2011.205062/full) discusses the right way to present error bars graphically. The paper mentions that the *confidence interval of the mean* should be used instead of standard error of the mean when comparing means is the goal. The paper also mentions the *confidence interval of the population*, but fails to describe the difference between *population* and *mean* CIs. I have not been able to find descriptions of these differences or formulas used. Is the CI of the mean the "regular" definition of CI based on Z or t distributions? If so, what is the CI of the population? Presumably the distinction is not the same as SD of the sample vs SD of the population.

Comment: Confidence intervals refer to population parameters, not to populations. Maybe the authors meant something like the range between the 2.5% and the 97.5% of the distribution (either of the sample or the population?).

Comment: "Confidence interval of the population" doesn't really make sense to me. some additional context might help (please also include a complete reference)

Answer (score 2):

**The Sample Mean**
If we were to repeatedly draw samples from the population, calculate the mean and construct $(1-\alpha) \cdot 100\%$ confidence intervals each time, then $(1-\alpha) \cdot 100\%$ of these intervals contain the population mean.

Here, the confidence interval is **a measure of precision** of the estimate. The narrower, the more precise our estimate.

**The Population**
Although I wouldn't call this a 'confidence interval' for the exact reason you are confused, the range described here contains $(1-\alpha) \cdot 100\%$ of the values in the population.

Here, the interval is **a measure of dispersion** around the true mean. It describes where we expect most values to be.

As ocram mentioned, a better way to call this is a prediction interval.

Comment: In that case, the interval is called a prediction interval.